# How do I run example in SideMenu library?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to run this [example](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/tree/master/Example). I'm almost entirely new to xcode, and can't figure out how to run that in the simulator. I download the library, and then open it into xcode. After hitting the build button, nothing happens. I'd appreciate a clue or hint. Thanks.

Comment: @matt Thanks. I was able to generate useful error messages that appear to tell me what I need to know. I'm pretty sure I can follow the breadcrumbs to the end now.

Comment: I provided revised instructions as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this page: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Click Clone Or Download and download the .zip file. Unzip it and open the folder.

Locate *SideMenu.xcworkspace*. Double-click it. Xcode opens it (after asking you if you really want to do this).

Switch the scheme to SideMenu (SideMenu project).

[image]

Build.

Switch the scheme to Example.

[image]

Build. Run.

[image]

Comment: Well, you were right to be frustrated. It’s not an obvious layout. They could have provided better instructions for running the example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above better run "pod update" prior to building the project and attempting to run the example. I used XCode 11.
Project should have had instructions on running the example.

Comment: Thanks, we backed off going native for awhile but I'm going to bookmark your answer for when we get back on that horse.